# Calculate object position in screen space - camera canvas

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, canvas

I'm in need of calculate the correct position of a 3D object which I'm displaying over a RawImage in my UI. If I put my UI image in the center of the screen I can calculate it perfectly, if I move my image around my UI canvas I'm getting results which are off by an offset, depending on the side I'm moving. I've taken a couple of screenshot of what I mean, the orange side is my 3D quad, the white square is just an image debugging where my point should be calculated.

[image: Correct visualization, image in the center of the screen]

[image: Image moved to the left side of the screen, wrong result]

The setup I have is this:
- a world camera pointing on a 3D quad
- a ui canvas with a dedicated perspective camera (Screen space - Camera)
- a panel in my ui canvas displaying the 3D quad

The code:

```cs
var worldPoint = t.Value.MeshRenderer.bounds.min; //t.Value is the 3D quad
var screenPoint = worldCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(worldPoint);
screenPoint.z = (baseCanvas.transform.position - uiCamera.transform.position).magnitude; //baseCanvas is the UI canvas
var pos = uiCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(screenPoint);
debugger.transform.position = pos; //debugger is just the square image used to see where my calculated point is landing
```

I've tried multiple ways, like this:

```cs
var screenPoint = worldCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(t.Value.MeshRenderer.bounds.min);
Vector2 localPoint;
RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(rectTransform, screenPoint, uiCamera, out localPoint); //rectTransform is my UI panel
debugger.transform.localPosition = localPoint
```

But I always get the same result, how can I make the correct calculation considering the offset?

Comment: Which position exactly do you want to get? `bounds.min`? what is the `(baseCanvas.transform.position - uiCamera.transform.position).magnitude;` supposed to be? (This would probably only work if there is no x/y offset between them. Why not simply `(baseCanvas.transform.position - uiCamera.transform.position).z`?

Comment: actually a Screen an will always have `0` distance to the camera. Probably you rather want the z distance to the `t.Value` instead?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for bounds.min position. That magnitude was a tentative in calculating the point accounting the for the offset, it didn't work though